# Flex-Wrap doesn´t start at the same level

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to do a flex-wrap to position the labels, but the main one does not start at the beginning and the others are at the same level

[image: flex-positions]

Snippet:

```css
.list {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 3.5px 10.1px 4.5px 13px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background-color: #d5f5ff;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">React Js</li>
  <li class="item">Python</li>
  <li class="item">Solidity</li>
  <li class="item">PHP</li>
  <li class="item">C#.Net</li>
  <li class="item">Linux</li>
  <li class="item">Diseño UX & UI</li>
  <li class="item">JavaScript</li>
  <li class="item">Scrum</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hello, you can see that your snippet doesn't reflect your screenshot, are you sure that this is all the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code is working fine. There must be some other code or element which is creating some issue. Please remove the other parent code to debug.

Here is the code sandbox link for your ref.
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-shtern-2k1e74?file=/style.css:0-312

```css
.list {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 3.5px 10.1px 4.5px 13px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background-color: #d5f5ff;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item">React Js</li>
      <li class="item">Python</li>
      <li class="item">Solidity</li>
      <li class="item">PHP</li>
      <li class="item">C#.Net</li>
      <li class="item">Linux</li>
      <li class="item">Diseño UX & UI</li>
      <li class="item">JavaScript</li>
      <li class="item">Scrum</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```